# PyQt4 QWebview error after initial evaluateJavaScript() call

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

I've got a Python 2.7 application running with PyQt4 that has a QWebView in it, that has two way communication to and from Javascript.

The application is multithreaded via QThreadPool, QRunnables, so I'm communicating with a ViewController class with signals.

When I run the application, the QWebView loads my HTML with external JS and CSS just fine. I'm able to interact with the Javascript functions via the main program thread and ViewController class.

Once the user selects a directory and certain criteria are met, it starts looping through QRunnable tasks one at a time. During that time it calls back to the ViewController -> Javascript via Signal slots, just as expected. The problem is when I'm calling those ViewController methods that execute evaluateJavaScript, I get a Javascript error returned,

> undefined line 1: SyntaxError: Parse error

I've done lots of trial error back and forth, but can't seem to figure out why evaluateJavaScript won't run in these instances. I've tried sending simple Javascript calls ranging from test functions that don't accept any arguments (thinking maybe it was some weird encoding issue), to just sending things like `Application.main.evaluateJavaScript("alert('foo')")`, which normally work outside of the threads. The only other thing I can think of is that maybe `self.main.addToJavaScriptWindowObject('view', self.view)` needs to be called in the threads again, but I've run a dir() on Application.main and it appears to have the evaluateJavaScript method attached to it already.

Any thoughts on why this could be occurring, when the scope seems to be correct, and the ViewController appears to be communicating just fine to the QWebView otherwise? Answers in Qt C++ will probably work as well, if you've seen this happen before!

I tried to simplify the code for example purposes:

```
# coding: utf8
import subprocess as sp

import os.path, os, sys, time, datetime
from os.path import basename
import glob

import random
import string

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QThreadPool, QRunnable, pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from ImportController import *


class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800,500)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setMargin(0)

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.html = QtWebKit.QWebView()

        # for javascript errors
        errors = WebPage()
        self.html.setPage(errors)

        self.main = self.html.page().mainFrame()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.html)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        path = os.getcwd()

        if self.checkNetworkAvailability() and self.checkApiAvailbility():
            self.default_url = "file://"+path+"/View/mainView.html"
        else:
            self.default_url = "file://"+path+"/View/errorView.html"

        # load the html view
        self.openView()

        # controller class that sends and receives to/from javascript
        self.view = ViewController()
        self.main.addToJavaScriptWindowObject('view', self.view)

        # on gui load finish
        self.html.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loadFinished)

    # to javascript

    def selectDirectory(self):
        # This evaluates the directory we've selected to make sure it fits the criteria, then parses the XML files
        pass


    def evaluateDirectory(self, directory):

        if not directory:
            return False

        if os.path.isdir(directory):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_loadFinished(self):

        # open directory select dialog
        self.selectDirectory()

    def openView(self):

        self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.default_url))
        self.html.show()

    def checkNetworkAvailability(self):
        #TODO: make sure we can reach the outside world before trying anything else
        return True

    def checkApiAvailbility(self):
        #TODO: make sure the API server is alive and responding
        return True


class WebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
        print '%s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg)

class ViewController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewController, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def did_load(self):
        print "View Loaded."

    @pyqtSlot()
    def selectDirectoryDialog(self):
        # FROM JAVASCRIPT: in case they need to re-open the file dialog
        Application.selectDirectory()

    def prepareImportView(self, displayPath):
        # TO JAVASCRIPT: XML directory parsed okay, so let's show the main
        Application.main.evaluateJavaScript("prepareImportView('{0}');".format(displayPath))

    def generalMessageToView(self, target, message):
        # TO JAVASCRIPT: Send a general message to a specific widget target
        Application.main.evaluateJavaScript("receiveMessageFromController('{0}', '{1}')".format(target, message))


    @pyqtSlot()
    def startProductImport(self):
        # FROM JAVASCRIPT: Trigger the product import loop, QThreads
        print "### view.startProductImport"
        position = 1
        count = len(Application.data.products)

        importTasks = ProductImportQueue(Application.data.products)
        importTasks.start()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def updateProductView(self, data):
        # TO JAVASCRIPT: Send product information to view
        print "### updateProductView "
        Application.main.evaluateJavaScript('updateProductView("{0}");'.format(QtCore.QString(data)) )


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    ''' Declares the signals that will be broadcast to their connected view methods '''
    productResult = pyqtSignal(str)

class ProductImporterTask(QRunnable):
    ''' This is where the import process will be fired for each loop iteration '''
    def __init__(self, product):
        super(ProductImporterTask, self).__init__()

        self.product = product
        self.count = ""
        self.position = ""
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self):
        print "### ProductImporterTask worker {0}/{1}".format(self.position, self.count)

        # Normally we'd create a dict here, but I'm trying to just send a string for testing purposes
        self.signals.productResult.emit(data)

        return

class ProductImportQueue(QObject):
    ''' The synchronous threadpool that is going to one by one run the import threads '''
    def __init__(self, products):
        super(ProductImportQueue, self).__init__()

        self.products = products
        self.pool = QThreadPool()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)

    def process_result(self, product):
        return

    def start(self):
        ''' Call the product import worker from here, and format it in a predictable way '''

        count = len(self.products)
        position = 1
        for product in self.products:

            worker = ProductImporterTask("test")

            worker.signals.productResult.connect(Application.view.updateProductView, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)
            self.pool.start(worker)
            position = position + 1

        self.pool.waitForDone()




if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Application = Browser()
    Application.raise_()
    Application.show()
    Application.activateWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You know, I love PyQt4 but after searching and searching, I believe this is actually a bug and not as designed.

I've since moved on and am trying to implement this in CEFPython with WxPython, which seems to have a much more elegant implementation for this specific purpose.